# AWS API Gateway Cannot GET / when function sleeped for long time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My current stack is AWS API Gateway --> AWS Lambda --> swagger-node + swagger-express-mw + aws-serverless-express.

So my Swagger API is hosted as one node.js Lambda Function and Invoked with aws_proxy from API Gateway. This works quite good. The only thing is that when the function sleeped for too long (cold start?) I get a `Cannot GET /` as Output from every URL I am calling first. From 2nd Request on, it runs very fast. Any ideas on that?

I don't think that it comes from API Gateway Integration Timeout as that are 30 seconds. The slowest invocation time of the function directly via lambda is around 2,5s and when it is called more often it is normally not more than 150ms. I also increased the Time of Lambda Timeout for that function to 10s so from there should also not come an error.

*Logs from Test Request via API Gateway first Invocation*

***Response Body***

```
Cannot GET /hello
```

***Response Headers***

```
{
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "18",
    "date": "Sun, 19 Feb 2017 15:00:11 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "<TRACE-ID>"
}
```

***Logs***

```
Execution log for request test-request
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /hello
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {}
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: 
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:<ACCOUNT-ID>:function:api/invocations
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=test-request, Authorization=**************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************4b0637, X-Amz-Date=20170219T150007Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=965h04axki, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_965h04axki, X-Amz-Security-Token=<SECURITY-TOKEN>
Sun Feb 19 15:00:07 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/hello","path":"/hello","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"accountId":"<ACCOUNT-ID>","resourceId":"ll6gw8","stage":"test-invoke-stage","requestId":"test-invoke-request","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"accountId":"<ACCOUNT-ID>","cognitoIdentityId":null,"caller":"<ACCOUNT-ID>","apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","sourceIp":"test-invoke-source-ip","accessKey":"<ACCESS-ID>","cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:root","userAgent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_102)","user":"<ACCOUNT-ID>"},"resourcePath":"/hello","httpMethod":"GET","apiId":"965h04axki"},"body":null,"isBase64Encoded":false}
Sun Feb 19 15:00:11 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":404,"body":"Cannot GET /hello\n","headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","content-length":"18","date":"Sun, 19 Feb 2017 15:00:11 GMT","connection":"close"},"isBase64Encoded":false}
Sun Feb 19 15:00:11 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, x-amzn-RequestId=19f8554e-f6b4-11e6-8184-d3ccf0ccf643, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=267, Date=Sun, 19 Feb 2017 15:00:11 GMT, Content-Type=application/json}
Sun Feb 19 15:00:11 UTC 2017 : Method response body after transformations: Cannot GET /hello

Sun Feb 19 15:00:11 UTC 2017 : Method response headers: {x-powered-by=Express, x-content-type-options=nosniff, content-type=text/html; charset=utf-8, content-length=18, date=Sun, 19 Feb 2017 15:00:11 GMT, connection=close, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-58a9b2f7-91fc7371e41d6ae9c2fbf64d}
Sun Feb 19 15:00:11 UTC 2017 : Successfully completed execution
Sun Feb 19 15:00:11 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 404
```

*Logs from Test Request via API Gateway second Invocation*

***Response Body***

```
"Hello, stranger!"
```

***Response Headers***

```
{
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "18",
    "etag": "W/\"12-E1p7iNXxJ4trMdmFBhlU9Q\"",
    "date": "Mon, 13 Feb 2017 20:12:36 GMT",
    "connection": "close",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "<Trace-ID>"
}
```

***Logs***

```
Execution log for request test-request
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /hello
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {}
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: 
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:<LAMBDA-FUNCTION-ID>:function:api/invocations
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=test-request, Authorization=*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************3e1b18, X-Amz-Date=20170213T201236Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=965h04axki, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:<ACCOUNT-ID>:965h04axki/null/GET/hello, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_965h04axki, X-Amz-Security-Token=<TOKEN>
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/hello","path":"/hello","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":null,"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"accountId":"<ACCOUNT-ID>","resourceId":"ll6gw8","stage":"test-invoke-stage","requestId":"test-invoke-request","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"accountId":"<ACCOUNT-ID>","cognitoIdentityId":null,"caller":"427402682812","apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","sourceIp":"test-invoke-source-ip","accessKey":"<ACCESS-KEY>","cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"cognitoAuthenticationProvider":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:root","userAgent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.x (Java/1.8.0_102)","user":"<ACCOUNT-ID>"},"resourcePath":"/hello","httpMethod":"GET","apiId":"965h04axki"},"body":null,"isBase64Encoded":false}
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":200,"body":"\"Hello, stranger!\"","headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","access-control-allow-origin":"*","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"18","etag":"W/\"12-E1p7iNXxJ4trMdmFBhlU9Q\"","date":"Mon, 13 Feb 2017 20:12:36 GMT","connection":"close"},"isBase64Encoded":false}
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Endpoint response headers: {x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, x-amzn-RequestId=c3354327-f228-11e6-8c1d-ed11cc413770, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=315, Date=Mon, 13 Feb 2017 20:12:36 GMT, Content-Type=application/json}
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Method response body after transformations: "Hello, stranger!"
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Method response headers: {x-powered-by=Express, access-control-allow-origin=*, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=18, etag=W/"12-E1p7iNXxJ4trMdmFBhlU9Q", date=Mon, 13 Feb 2017 20:12:36 GMT, connection=close, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-58a21334-8ea6c4b5944eebb873bc7d2e}
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Successfully completed execution
Mon Feb 13 20:12:36 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the response "Cannot GET /" is coming from your Lambda function itself. Can you check API Gateway CW logs (or Test Invoke feature in console) to see what's different in the integration request and response in the first call?

Comment: Good point. I added the logs from first and second Invocation via API Gateway

Comment: Yeah it's definitely coming from the Lambda function, which appears to be a serverless express module. Can you increase the Lambda function timeout in the Lambda settings? That would probably help if the express server takes more than 2.5 seconds to initialize.

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS thx for the hint. I increased it and now it works. But for the first time I didn't get a 500 but a 404. I replaced the logs on top.

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS for me the weird thing ist that
`Endpoint request body after transformations` is the same for both. but first time I get a 404 and 2nd time a 200

Comment: Is it the same? The statusCode and body are both different

Comment: @JackKohn-AWS you are right the StatusCode and Body are different but in the Logs the `Endpoint request body after transformations` is the same for both. And I do not understand why for first invocation the answer is a 404 even if I increased Lambda to timeout 10s and from the 2nd invocation on it does work with the same request and the answer then is a 200. The requests should be totally equal I just refresh my browser or Test Request in API Gateway without a difference. That is weird.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any real documentation about it (just [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@tjholowaychuk/dos-and-don-ts-of-aws-lambda-7dfcab7ad115#.r3w8o7xrv)) but I also experienced the fact that a Lambda can be frozen until the first invocation, or in the case it's not called for a long time.

A solution is to schedule a regular invocation to wake up your lambda, with [Amazon CloudWatch Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)

Comment: Of course I know that solution but in my opinion that is only a bad solution. I will do it in production if there is no better one but I thought that topic would be worth a question to get a charming solution ;) Because if AWS wants to push Lambda forward there should not be an error like that

Answer (score 0):

I know that is an old question, but if you use TypeORM (or more in general, if you wrap all your Express middlewares within a `.then()` callback of a Promise), and you use `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` in your lambda handler, maybe this could help you: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5894
Long story short: avoid to set that flag to false, if possible, otherwise avoid to wrap the Express middlewares within the .then() callback and, for instance, initialize your db connection in the first Express middleware.